# Correct way to manage bundle id's for alpha / beta / release channels with fastlane

Tags: android, testing, deployment, fastlane, google-play-console

I've set up my app with 2 flavours `development` and `production`. Where difference is in database's they use.

I want to deploy `development` to alpha lane and `production` to beta / release lanes.

So far had no issues acheiving this with fast lane, but I have a question.
In my flavours I specify different bundle id's for each flavour e.g. `com.example.myApp` and `com.example.myApp-development`

Fastlane only allows me to specify one, same goes for google play console. Hence the question:

What's the correct approach here? Do I just use 1 bundle id for all flavours and deploy them to respective testing lanes?

Or am I better of creating 2 apps in my play console (which I am kinda against now). I haven't worked with android releases closely, so am not sure what the common way is for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to get right is vocabulary. "bundle id" is an iOS term without a definition on Android.

On Android the term is "package name" (eg com.example.myapp). A package name uniquely identifies an app on Android. Two different package names means two different apps.

For most apps the recommended approach is to use the same package name for alpha, beta and production. That way it is less confusing for the users, and if there is no current live alpha/beta version the users will get the production version (they won't get "left behind" on an old alpha). It also means that you have only one Play store listing to maintain with screenshots etc.

A few apps (eg Chrome) have a separate package name (app) for beta testing. Chrome does this because they had a beta version before the Play store supported beta versions. However, it also gives you the advantage that you can have the beta and the production version on the same device and run them side by side. Most app developers don't do this however, and I'd recommend not to.

Comment: >For most apps the recommended approach is to use the same package name for alpha, beta and production
That statement is not true. All the apps I have worked on have seperate bundle ids for alpha/beta/production. It makes it easier to release hotfixes to production when you are still beta testing new features for a major release.